# Generating Expression<Func<T, object>> arguments

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I have a method like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Pager<T>(T urlParams, Expression<Func<T, object>> pageProperty) where T : class
{
        string pagingProp = Helpers.PropertyToString(pageProperty.Body);
        //set property on object using reflection.
        PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty(urlParams.GetType());

}
```

The purpose of the expression is to know what property of `urlParams` is the one that should be used for paging.

Lets say I have the class:

```
public class Pagination
{
    public int PageIndex {get; set; }
}
```

I would like to call it like this:

```
Html.Pager(new Pagination{ PageIndex = 1 }, new Expression<Func<Pagination>>(p => p.PageIndex))
```

Problem: `Expression<Func<Pagination>>()` does take a constructor, how do I tell the expression I want to use the `PageIndex` property?

Comment: I don't understand the question; why can you not simply pass one expression?

Comment: @EricLippert thats what I want to do, but I don't know how to create it. Or better yet, I would like an example of just passing `Password` using `Expression<Func<User, object>>`

Comment: You're going to have to explain this to us like we don't know what you're talking about, because we don't know what you're talking about. What is "User" and "Password"?  What are you "passing" them *to*?  Start from the beginning and describe your scenario in detail; we don't have the context you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming:

```
void M(Expression<Func<User, object>> f) { /* ... some implementation ... */ }
```

Then:

```
M(u => u.Password);
```

Comment: Yup... I *think* that this is what the OP is asking. I was just typing it up as well.

Comment: Do you mean `Expression<Func<User, object>>`?